# How to make cursor rotate

Tags: c++, c

What i am trying to is to do something like this:

Print `\` then `|` then `/` then `_` and it goes on in a loop. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{ 
   while(1)
   {
           printf("\\");
           printf("|");
           printf("/");
           printf("_");
   }
   return 0;  
}
```

The problem i face is that it prints it in a sequence, how do i make it print at the same cursor position with some time delay in C or C++?

Comment: Please `#include <cstdio>`, not `#include <stdio.h>`, when writing C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't properly understand what you mean by `How to make cursor rotate`? But were you by any chance wanting to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h>  

#define mydelay 100

void delay(int m)
{
    clock_t wait = m+ clock();
    while (wait > clock());
}


int main()  
{  
   while(1)
   {
           printf("\\\b");
           delay(mydelay);
           printf("|\b");
           delay(mydelay);
           printf("/\b");
           delay(mydelay);
           printf("_\b");
           delay(mydelay);
   }

   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it's completely dependent on the environment whether this works or not. And `clock()` usually measures CPU time for the process, not wall time.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{ 
   while(1)
   {
           printf("\\");  printf("%c", 8); // 8 is the backspace ASCII code.
           printf("|");  printf("%c", 8);  // %c is the printf format string for single character
           printf("/");  printf("%c", 8);  // assuming output to a terminal that understands
           printf("_");  printf("%c", 8);  // Backspace processing,  this works.
   }
   return 0;  
}
```

If you need a delay, then add a call to your own delay function that busy-waits, or calls sleep, or does some other processing.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for sleep() */

int main(void)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"Here we are:  ");

  while(1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"\b\\");
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(stderr,"\b|");
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(stderr,"\b/");
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(stderr,"\b-");
    sleep(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a backspace character (`\b`) after printing, though whether this works is completely up to the environment where your program's output is being displayed.

You'll also want to introduce a delay so that you can actually see the changes (though this may happen naturally, as part of your wider algorithm).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()  
{ 
   while(1) {
           printf("\\\b"); sleep(1);
           printf("|\b");  sleep(1);
           printf("/\b");  sleep(1);
           printf("_\b");  sleep(1);
   }
   return 0;  
}
```

You could also look into [the curses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) for proper text-based GUI fu.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a carriage return to the beginning of you stings.

e.g.

```
printf("\r|");
sleep(1);
```

or add a backspace after printing.-

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this in either C or C++.

You can use a third party library like ncurses or ANSI escape sequences (if on Unix OS).

Answer (score 0):

In C you can print a backspace character using '\b' or ascii value 8. Use that before each print. I guess you'll need some delay between 2 print statements.

Comment: If you are in Linux, there is the curses library for doing this.